# How to update multiple firebase child values based on each child autogeneratedID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i update  all changes made on recyclerview  editText to all firebased data based on each item autogenerated id.

This is how i get data in recyclerview:

```
StudentdatabaseReference.child(GroupId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            editModelArrayList = new ArrayList<AddStudentModel>();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                AddStudentModel value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(AddStudentModel.class);
                AddStudentModel fire = new AddStudentModel();
                String name = value.getStudentName();
                String id = value.getStudentID();
                fire.setStudentName(name);
                fire.setStudentID(id);
                editModelArrayList.add(fire);
            }
            customAdapter = new UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter(AddStudent.this,editModelArrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("Hello", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

This is how i got for updating on button clicked, app is keep on crashing

```
 update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    for (int i = 0; i <  UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter .editModelArrayList.size(); i++){
        AddStudentModel mylist = editModelArrayList.get(i);

        String ky =mylist.getStudentID();      
 StudentdatabaseReference.child(GroupId).child(ky).child("name").setValue(UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.editModelArrayList.get(i).getEditTextValue());
    } }});
```

Here is adapter Class

```
 public class UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
public static ArrayList<AddStudentModel> editModelArrayList;

  public UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<AddStudentModel> editModelArrayList){

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.editModelArrayList = editModelArrayList;
}

@Override
public UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_student_rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    AddStudentModel mylist = editModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(mylist.getStudentID());
    holder.editText.setText(mylist.getStudentName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return editModelArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected EditText editText;
    protected TextView textView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_view);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText.getText().toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                editModelArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setEditTextValue(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

[image: database structure]

Any one so that can help or better idea/ way to make this work..
Thank You

layout

```
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_add_scores"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

recycler item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_view"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your database structure?  Also, your use case is not clear. Please explain. Do you want to update student name when ever the editest value is changed?

Comment: @JerinAMathews A Mathews           whenever i made changes and i want to keep them

Comment: where is this `update.setOnclickListener` situated, in activity or adapter? and does every user item have update button ? Add your recycler view layout design too.

Comment: 1: update.setOnclickListener is in activity      2; no  there is only one button outside recyclerview when clicked  send all data to the database  @Jerin A Mathews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is, you tried to call the arraylist in the adapter from the activity. You cant do that. So what you have to do is, create an interface which will update the arraylist in the activity when a change is made in the recycler view.
Heres how to achieve it:

First, create an interface like this:

```
public interface RecyclerItemClick {

public void onItemClick(int position, String newValue);
}
```

This will be called when a user makes changes in edit text.

add `implements RecyclerItemClick`, in your activity and overide the `onItemClick()` function.

Declare recycler view and adapter outside the database function , pass RecyclerItemClick object into the adapter. Then call `customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after getting data from database.

```
 customAdapter = new UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter(AddStudent.this,editModelArrayList, this);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
 StudentdatabaseReference.child(GroupId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        editModelArrayList = new ArrayList<AddStudentModel>();
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            AddStudentModel value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(AddStudentModel.class);
            AddStudentModel fire = new AddStudentModel();
            String name = value.getStudentName();
            String id = value.getStudentID();
            fire.setStudentName(name);
            fire.setStudentID(id);
            editModelArrayList.add(fire);
        }
     customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w("Hello", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

Then in the adapter,

```
 public class UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter extends 
 RecyclerView.Adapter<UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

 private LayoutInflater inflater;
 RecyclerItemClick itemClick;
 public static ArrayList<AddStudentModel> editModelArrayList;

 public UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<AddStudentModel> 
  editModelArrayList,RecyclerItemClick itemClick){

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
    this.editModelArrayList = editModelArrayList;
    this.itemClick = itemClick;
 }

@Override
public UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_student_rv_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UpdateStudentRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    AddStudentModel mylist = editModelArrayList.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(mylist.getStudentID());
    holder.editText.setText(mylist.getStudentName());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return editModelArrayList.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected EditText editText;
    protected TextView textView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        editText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editid);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_view);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                itemClick.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), editText.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Now whenever a change is made in the editText, the interface function in activity will be called. Now in the overide onItemClick() function , update the arraylist like this:

```
@override
public void onItemClick(int position, String newValue){
      editModelArrayList.get(position).setEditTextValue(newValue); // i assume, this is where u store updated value.
}
```

Now, on update.setOnClickListener() :

```
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       for (int i = 0; i <  editModelArrayList.size(); i++){
          AddStudentModel mylist = editModelArrayList.get(i);

          String ky =mylist.getStudentID();      
          StudentdatabaseReference.child(GroupId).child(ky).child("name").setValue(mylist.getEditTextValue());
} }});
```

I think this will work. Try it.